# Voice artist for a game for kids

Tags: sound, assets, voice

We're making a game for kids which should include about 50 spoken phrases. I'm asking for help in finding the right voice artist / studio for this. I've tried searching the web but couldn't find anything that would make me sure that it would work for us or games in general. So I'm looking for references from those of you who had a successful collaboration with artists or studios. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the place to get references for artists or studios. A question that just generates a list of answers, doesn't have a correct answer and isn't a proper question for the site.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an idea. I  haven't tested it. But isn't it possible to simply record it and edit the record using some filters/effects to make it sound like you want? Tools like Audacity or GarageBand might be a point to start.

I think that the main trick is to have a soft low voice, so try to pull down the pitch of the recording with one of those tools. And when recording, try to speak slowly.

As I already said, that is what I should give a try. Not sure if the results will be good. Good luck!

Comment: and make sure to speak in major/edit it to a major key - kids repond better and comprehend the sound better when it is in major